# Delete Confirmation Message Closes Prematurely in Rails App

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I have a coffeescript file that overrides the rails confirmation pop-up and instead uses bootstrap modal to confirm the delete action.

```
#delete.js.coffee
ready = ->

    $.rails.allowAction = (element) ->
      message = element.data('confirm')
      return true unless message

      $link = element.clone()
        .removeAttr('class')
        .removeAttr('data-confirm')
        .addClass('btn').addClass('btn-danger')
        .html("Delete")

      modal_html = """
                                    <div class="modal fade">
                                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                          <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">#{message}</h4>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="modal-body">
                                            <p>Be certain, sony.</p>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</a>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>  
                   """
      $modal_html = $(modal_html)
      $modal_html.find('.modal-footer').append($link)
      $modal_html.modal()
      return false

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

The code above works properly unless it is called from a table when the modal pops up correctly but then quickly closes. The table has a clickable row functionality which links to the show view.

```
#users.js.coffee
ready = ->
  $("tr[data-link]").click ->
    window.location = @dataset.link
    return

  return

$(document).ready ready
$(document).on "page:load", ready
```

Here is the body of the table where the clickable tr exist with the embed link to delete the user:

```
    #index.html.erb
    <tbody>
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <tr data-link="<%= user_path(user) %>">
          <td><%= user.name %></td>
          <td><%= user.email %></td>
          <td><%= user_status(user) %>
            <% unless current_account.owner == user || user.invitation_accepted? %>
              <%= form_for(User.new, url: user_invitation_path) do |f| %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :email, :value => user.email %>
                <%= f.submit 'Resend Invite', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
              <% end %>  
            <% end %>                     
          </td>
          <td>
            <% unless current_account.owner == user %>
              <%= link_to '', user_path(user), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this user, no take backsies?'}, method: :delete, :class => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger' %>
            <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

This is part of a rails 4 app with turbolinks enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Two click events are binding to delete button , when its inside table .

You can ignore delete button when binding click event to table row

```
ready = ->
  $("tr[data-link]").not('[data-confirm]').click ->
    window.location = @dataset.link
    return

  return
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. The two click events makes perfect since. If I remove the custom data-confirm, a similar event takes place, the message doesn't close automatically, but if I cancel, it goes to the view  as dictated by the 2nd click event vs just close out the confirmation message.

Comment: can you show your view code , where you are facing this problem ?

Comment: I added the tbody with the tr link and the embedded delete link_to

Comment: why you added user_path(user) to delete link, doesn't make sense and maybe the cause of bug.

Comment: updated the code to: `<%= link_to '', user, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this user, no take backsies?'}, method: :delete, :class => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger' %>` but issue still exists, hmmm, this issue just wants to keep fighting.

Comment: <%= link_to '', '#', data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this user, no take backsies?'}, method: :delete, :class => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger' %>

Comment: @Steve If the project you are working on is opensource then I can checkout it on local and figure out what's wrong.